# Maven on Windows not able to resolve parent POM from a custom library added as a dependency

Tags: java, windows, maven

I'm testing a multi module project on maven and also creating custom libraries to include in other Maven projects, and Im building a math-util lib, which is one of the modules of my project, so I have this folder structure

```
/parent-util
    /math-util
        pom.xml
pom.xml
```

This is the `pom.xml` of `parent-utl`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.javi</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-util</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>math-util</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

And this is the `pom.xml` of `math-util`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.javi</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-util</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>math-util</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

After running `mvn clean install` I get the following jar file for my `math-util` library `math-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Then I created another maven project, which I named `demo` my idea was to include the `math-util` library as a dependency, using a local repository inside `demo` (think about this as a customer who we are only providing the `math-util` jar file), so this is my folder structure for the `demo` project (I just copied and pasted the `math-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` inside so I can install it)

```
/demo
    /lib
    /src/java/...
    math-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    pom.xml
```

By using `mvn install` I installed my `math-lib` dependency inside the `lib` folder:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile='math-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar' -DgroupId='com.javi' -DartifactId='math-util' -Dversion='1.0-SNAPSHOT' -DlocalRepositoryPath='lib'
```

Which works fine and I actually see the folders now inside `lib`, this is the output

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< org.example:demo >--------------------------
[INFO] Building demo 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- install:3.1.0:install-file (default-cli) @ demo ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\jmeza\IdeaProjects\demo\math-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\jmeza\IdeaProjects\demo\lib\com\javi\math-util\1.0-SNAPSHOT\math-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\jmeza\AppData\Local\Temp\math-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT973893646697774711.pom to C:\Users\jmeza\IdeaProjects\demo\lib\com\javi\math-util\1.0-SNAPSHOT\math-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.499 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-04T10:05:30-06:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now my `pom.xml` for `demo` is the following, adding the `lib` folder as a repository and the `math-util` as a dependency

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>lib</id>
            <name>Local Maven Repository</name>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/lib</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.javi</groupId>
            <artifactId>math-util</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

But I dont know why, and this is only failing for me on Windows (tried it on Ubuntu and Mac) when I try to do `mvn clean install` I get the following issue

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< org.example:demo >--------------------------
[INFO] Building demo 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.394 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-04T10:26:06-06:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project demo: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.example:demo:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.javi:math-util:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read arti
fact descriptor for com.javi:math-util:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.javi:parent-util:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT (absent): com.javi:parent-util:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT was not found in file://C:
\Users\jmeza\IdeaProjects\demo/lib during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of lib has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Which indicates maven is not able to resolve the parent POM file in this case `parent-util`, the weird thing is this is only failing for me on Windows

I have tried using `<relativePath>` on the `math-util` pom.xml file but it didnt work, also I tried changing the `<url>` inside the `demo` pom.xml thinking if this is an issue with the `file://` protocol but even if I add a full path this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

On windows the default location for the "local" repository is `C:\Users\<User_Name>\.m2`.

Calling `mvn clean install` in "parent-util" should cause both `parent-util` AND `math-util` to be installed locally.

There is no need to install the artifact or it's parent into your demo and you don't have to add `repositories` and `file://${project.basedir}/lib` etc..

Comment: Hi what I was testing is having the `math-util` jar file into another machine, to use it as a library, where I don't have the `parent-util` nor the `math-util` project in that machine, that's why Im defining a repository under `lib` and using the `<repositories>`, let's imagine this is a customer and we are just providing the Jar file to them

Comment: But that is not how Maven dependency management works. If your customer is't using maven, then they can add `<systemPath>${basedir}/lib/math-util-1.0.jar</systemPath>` (SNAPSHOTS are Maven internal) to their dependency.